# Is it correct to say "lend to me sth"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositional-phrases

Dictionaries usually recognize the following:

> lend me some money
>
> lend some money to me

So how about placing "to me" immediately after the verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean as in

> Lend **to me** some money?

It's not wrong, but it's much less common than your other examples because it sounds *poetic*, or at least *old-fashioned*.  The use is much the same as with similar verbs like "give", as in the song ["Leather and Lace"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLEMiDrdSKU):

> **Give to me** your leather, take from me my lace.

Or in certain translations of the Bible:

> Ahab speaketh unto Naboth, saying, '**Give to me** thy vineyard, that it may be to me for a garden of green herbs, for it is near by my house, and let me **give to thee** in its stead a better vineyard than it; if good in thine eyes, let me **give to thee** silver, its price.'

In the same way "lend to me" would sound fine if you are trying to write a sentence that sounds literary or archaic, but otherwise use one of the other forms.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that you can't say that, but it would sound rather unnatural and foreign to say it like that. I would stick to the more idiomatic way of saying it, and just say "**lend me**" or "**lend to**".